# COCO API displaying instance labels and scores

Tags: data-visualization, object-detection, mscoco

I've been looking COCO API Jupyter notebook examples like [this one](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocoDemo.ipynb). This is a simple example that shows how instance annotations can be overlaid. However, it doesn't show how to display labels (in multi-class cases) and scores (for predictions) on these annotations. Does this API offer that functionality at all?